# List of Classes? AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a list of classes and getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Here is the code:

```
class someclass:
    def __init__(self, somevariable):
        self.somevariable = somevariable

list = [[5],[5]]

for o in range(5):
    for i in range(5):
        list[o][i].append(someclass('data'))
```

I've tried doing this a number of ways and there are many google results that make me think this should work, but the error say otherwise.

Here is the short tutorial I was using, but it is not a multidimensional list.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-list-of-object-in-python-class/

Comment: try to see what `print(list[o][i])` is.

Comment: `list[o][i]` is `5`, which indeed doesn't have an `append` method.

Comment: What is your expected result for `list`? To append the classes, you could do `list.append(someclass("data"); list.append(someclass("other_data")`. `list[o][i]` is a number though.

Comment: what do you think this line is doing `list = [[5],[5]]`? And don't use `list` as name.

Comment: Also, think about why are you iterating over `range(5)`.

Comment: I'm trying to be able to reference x and y coordinates.  At each coordinate I could get the data from the class.  Something like a tick-tack-toe board, but with each location having more data than just "X" or "O".

Comment: @buran I assumed the that line was creating the list that I would them populate. I'm pretty new to Python. I've been watching videos and reading, but every now and then I get ahead of myself. If I remove it I get an error that it's not defined and if I don't specify the size I get out of range errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Note 1

When you are debugging code, try to remove all of the code which is not related to the problem at hand.

For example, if you are debugging a function named `paint_a_house` remove the code for `change_flat_car_tire`

extraneous/superfluous code gets in the way of fixing things.

Below is your original code:

```python
class someclass:
    def __init__(self, somevariable):
        self.somevariable = somevariable

list = [[5],[5]]

for o in range(5):
    for i in range(5):
        list[o][i].append(someclass('data'))
```

We really do not need the ***class*** named `someclass`:

```python
list = [[5],[5]]

for o in range(5):
    for i in range(5):
        list[o][i].append(4)
```

Now we have code which produces the exact same error.
The mistake is still there, but it is easier to see, because extraneous stuff has been removed.

## Note 2

What does the error message `'int' object has no attribute 'append'`  actually mean?

An `int` is a whole-number, such as `1`, `2`, `3`, ..., `100`, `972391`, etc...

Your code produces the same error as the following:

```python
68.append("ham")
```

Note that you ***CANNOT*** append anything to an integer (`int`)

```python
list = [[5],[5]]
o = 0
i = 0
list[o][i].append(4)
```

Guess what? `list[o][i]` is an integer.

The following two columns are equivalent:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| `list = [[5],[5]]` | `list = [[5],[5]]` |
| `list[0]` | `[5]` |
| `list[0][0]` | `5` |
| `list[0][0].append(2)` | `5.append(2)` |

## Note 3

Never ***EVER*** name a variable `list`
`list` is the name of a very important class in python.
If you name your own stuff `list`, then we will not be able to use the real `list` class anymore.
This is called "name-shadowing"
Programmers say that the thing you named `list` "*shadows*" the real-thing named `list`

```python
list = [[5], [5]]

# the following would normally work, 
# but now, we will get an error.

lizzy = list(range(10))
```

Normally, `list(cookie_jar)` constructs a new list from a `cookie_jar`.

We write code, like the following:

```python
new_container = list(old_container)
```

However, when you write `list = 1` doing so changes the meaning of the word `list`

`list` is no longer a type of container. `list` is the number 1.

`new_container = list(old_container)` will not work anymore.

## Note 4

Your loop indices are too big.

Suppose that you have a list named "Larry."

- Larry has an item #0
- Larry has an item #1
- Larry has an item #2
- Larry has ***NO*** item #3

```python
x = Larry[0]   # WORKS FINE! GOOD CODE!
x = Larry[1]   # WORKS FINE!       
x = Larry[2]   # WORKS FINE!  
    
x = Larry[3]   # TERRIBLE! WRONG! BAD!  
x = Larry[4]   # BAD!
```

You wrote something like the following:

```python
list = [[5],[5]]

for o in range(5):
    for i in range(5):
        x = list[o][i]
```

Your list indices are too big.

`range(5)` is almost the same as `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Your code is somewhat like the following:

```python
list = [[5],[12]]

for o in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]:
    for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]:
        print(list[o][i])
```

`list` only has 2 items in it.

If `list == [[5],[12]]`

- `list[0]` is `[5]`
- `list[1]` is `[12]`
- `list[2]` does not exist
- `list[3]` does not exist
- et cetera

Stop using list indices which are too big.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.  This was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `list` is not a good name for a list, because you are overriding the built-in `list()` function.
You don't have to specify the length of a list in advance, so it's enough if you just say `l = []`. Then you need to restructure the for loop as follows:

```
l = []
for o in range(5):
    l.append([])
    for i in range(5):
        l[o].append(someclass('data'))
```

Comment: Remco646 thank you for taking the time to post this.  Is there any way to make it a multidimensional list?  Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for helping